# UITableView with self sizing cells becomes jerky when calling deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I have a UITableView with self sizing cells. Table contains 1 section and some rows.  I have some rows say 30 and I want to delete row during `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

When I delete a row available near the bottom of tableview (say 28th row ), the rows before 28th row changes their position and it causes jerky animation as a result of `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`. See attached gifs for more details.

[Cells constructed with frame deletion animation](https://giphy.com/gifs/GvMvf5gXrvpMA)

[Auto Resizing cells Deletion animation](https://giphy.com/gifs/K10VNkegCykog)

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {

       return 1;
  }
  -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
  }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return noOfRows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    CustomCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    [cell setCellText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section = %li Row = %li", indexPath.section,indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    noOfRows--;
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

This jerky animation happens only with self sizing cells and not with cells constructed with frame.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** The problem is content offset and content size. Lets say each cell in table view has height of 50. So for 20 cells the content size would be around 1000. Lets consider device height as 200 and width as 100.So the content size will be 100,1000. When I scroll to bottom of the tableview content offset becomes 0,800. When I delete a row now the content size will be updated to 100, 950 and content offset now tries to adjust to new value as a result of change in content size. So this causes Jerkiness.

Comment: try to put it in [tbView beginUpdates]; and [tbView endUpdates];

Comment: According to the gif its jerking also before deleting.

Comment: have you tried putting an estimated row height?

Comment: I put this in viewDidLoad [self.tableView setEstimatedRowHeight:50]. Even if I implement estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath no change .

Comment: Try `CustomCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];` instead of `CustomCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: @Poles It is not solving the Jerkiness. See Edit:1

Comment: after estimatedRowHeight, try to remove heightForRowAtIndexPath: and see if there will be changes

Comment: I removed heightForRowAtIndexPath and nothing changes

Comment: use only self sizing cells and see if the jerkiness is there?

Comment: I use purely self sizing cells and problem exists only with self sizing cells and not with ordinary cells constructed with frame

Comment: jsut a bit curious. Is didSelectRowAtIndexPath a good place to delete rows. You can use editing from tableview and its delegate method for deletion. my thoughts

Comment: Its just for simplicity of explaining the problem. I actually delete rows on click of a delete button available in the cell.

Comment: jsut some of my suggestions.Actually we don't manipulate content sizes etc. You can use the deletion mechanism provided by tableview and see if the problem exists? some suggestions from me :)

Comment: Even now I'm not manipulating content size and I'm using default deleteRowsAtIndexPaths method. My content size explanation was mainly to make readers to understand my problem correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jerky animation is due to incorrect estimated heights of your cells. So you need to implement `estimatedRowHeight` in your table view controller and return saved heights. You can save previously loaded cell heights in `willDisplayCell` tableView delegate methods as `cell.frame.size.height` in an array.

```
var estimatedHeights : [CGFloat] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
        if estimatedHeights.count > indexPath.row
        {
            return estimatedHeights[indexPath.row]
        }

        return 40

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{


        if estimatedHeights.count <= indexPath.row
        {
            estimatedHeights.append(cell.frame.height)

        }
        else
        {
            estimatedHeights[indexPath.row] = cell.frame.height

        }

}
```

Also put your delete code within `[tableView beginUpdates];` and `[tableView endUpdates];`

Comment: Hi your solution works for table with only one section. But in my case I have many sections with section header view constructed with auto layout. In such case jerkiness still exist. Reason is I return an arbitrary value in estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection say 100. In my willDisplayHeaderView I'm getting view's height as whatever I returned in estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection so in my case I get as 100. So how to get exact height of header view in  willDisplayHeaderView?

Comment: use another array, say estimatedHeaderHeights and save the height of the header view over there

Comment: I think u have not understood my comment for your answer. Im doing exactly like you suggested but still getting wrong value for height in willDisplayHeaderView.

Comment: If you are using a label , you can find out the height using sizethatFits. The label should have the same text and font to get it correctly. Try using that instead of automatic dimension and save that in array

Comment: Sorry @shinoys222 I can't do that because my app supports both portrait and Landscape orientation. If I implement like ur suggestion then it add burden of updating that label height array every time orientation changes. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: More over I was able to achieve this deletion without jerkiness in my sample   project but when I implement the same logic (like maintaining height arrays for both section headers and cells) in my main app the jerkiness still exists. Jerkiness goes away only if I return very small value say 1.001 in my estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection for first time like this,    NSNumber *sectionKey = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:section]; if ([headerHeightDictionary objectForKey:sectionKey]) { return [[headerHeightDictionary objectForKey:sectionKey] floatValue];} else
    {
        return 1.001;
    }

Comment: I think you should return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` while returning estimatedRowHeight if the array does not contain that section. As for the orientation it will be a big trouble to implement all this

Comment: When I returned UITablevViewAutomaticDimension in estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection, it makes table view jerky.

Comment: Nice Answer! Fixes all jerky animations on my dynamic cells updated by NSFetchedResultsController.

Answer (score 1):

Update your method like this and try:

**`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`**

```
[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
```

**`didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    noOfRows--;
[tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: No it is not solving the jerky animation with self sizing cells.

Comment: No bro the problem is content offset and content size. Lets say each cell in table view has height of 50. So for 20 cells the content size would be around 1000. Lets consider device height as 200 and width as 100.So the content size will be 100,1000. When I scroll to bottom of the tableview content offset becomes 0,800. When I delete a row now the content size will be updated to 100, 950 and content offset now tries to adjust to new value as a result of change in content size. So this causes Jerkiness.